# Refactoring into ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, refactoring, reactive-cocoa

So I have just recently started with ReactiveCocoa, and I figured the best way to learn would be just to jump right in and start refactoring some existing code that I have. I was wanting to get some critique and make sure I am heading in the right direction.

So in the app I am refactoring, I have a ton of code that goes like this:

```
[self.ff getArrayFromUri:@"/States?sort=name asc" onComplete:^(NSError *theErr, id theObj, NSHTTPURLResponse *theResponse) {
    if(!theErr) {
       //do something with theObj
    }
    else {
       //handle the error
    }
}];
```

I currently have this refactored in ReactiveCocoa like so:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
 //ReactiveCocoa
RACCommand *command = [RACCommand command];
RACSubject *subject = [RACSubject subject];
[[[command addSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id value) {
    NSError *err;
    NSArray *array = [self.ff getArrayFromUri:@"/States" error:&err];
    err ? [subject sendError:err] : [subject sendNext:array];
    return [RACSignal empty];
}]switchToLatest]deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];

[subject subscribeNext:^(NSArray *x) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSomeSegue sender:x];
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"the error = %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

self.doNotLocation = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.doNotLocation setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackButton_small.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[self.doNotLocation rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] executeCommand:command];
RAC(self.doNotLocation.enabled) = RACAbleWithStart(command, canExecute);
RAC([UIApplication sharedApplication],networkActivityIndicatorVisible) = RACAbleWithStart(command, executing);    }
```

Is this about how I should be going about it, using the RACSubject, or is there a better way? This whole concept is new to me, as my only programming languages thus far have been Java and Objective-C, so this functional reactive way of thinking is throwing me off a bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are a couple problems with the code sample you presented:

1. The block passed to `-addSignalBlock:` is returning an empty signal. That should be a warning flag, since there are almost never junk return values. In this case, it means that the block performs its work synchronously. To avoid blocking the main thread, you should *create a signal* which does that work asynchronously, and return it.
2. The `-switchToLatest` and `-deliverOn:` are not doing anything. Most signal operators only do work when the resulting signal is subscribed to. In this case, it just disappears into the aether.

We can solve both of these problems at once. `-addSignalBlock:` returns a signal of *the signals returned in the block*. If we return something meaningful, it can be handled outside of that method.

First of all, this needs to be added to the top:

```
@weakify(self);
```

When `@strongify(self)` is used below, it will prevent [a retain cycle](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/MemoryManagement.md#signals-derived-from-self). This is necessary because the `RACCommand` lives as long as `self`.

Now, the creation of the inner signals:

```
RACSignal *requestSignals = [command addSignalBlock:^(id value) {
    return [RACSignal start:^(BOOL *success, NSError **err) {
        @strongify(self);

        NSArray *array = [self.ff getArrayFromUri:@"/States" error:err];
        *success = (array != nil);

        return array;
    }];
}];
```

Within the block, this simply creates a signal which will invoke `-getArrayFromUri:error:` and pass back its results or an error, if one occurred. `+start:` will ensure that the work happens in the background.

Out of all of this, we get `requestSignals`, which is a signal *of those created signals*. This can completely replace the `RACSubject` used originally:

```
RACSignal *arrays = [[[requestSignals
    map:^(RACSignal *request) {
        return [request catch:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"the error = %@", error);
            return [RACSignal empty];
        }];
    }]
    flatten]
    deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];
```

First, we transform each inner signal to log, then ignore, errors. (It's a little complicated, but a RAC operator [might be added](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/527) to do it in the future.)

Then we [flatten](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#flattening) the signal of signals. The result, `arrays`, is a signal that passes through the values of *all* the inner signals. This is why we had to ignore errors – if any of them reached this point, we would stop getting all values from the inner signals, forever.

Finally, we "lift" the selector to invoke:

```
[self rac_liftSelector:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) withObjects:kSomeSegue, arrays];
```

This will resend `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` whenever `arrays` sends a new value (which will be an `NSArray` returned from the network). You can think of it like invoking a method *over time*. This is [better than a subscription](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#avoid-explicit-subscriptions-and-disposal) because it simplifies side effects and memory management.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do appreciate it. I am getting one problem with your provided code, in the second to last sample. `[request catch:]`  is saying that it needs to return a `RACSignal` and not void. Am I just missing something there?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're completely right. You can just return `[RACSignal empty]` (to indicate that the error signal should be replaced with an immediately-successful one). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, so I have everything updated, and it is working, except I get a substantial delay (about 3 second) and also it seems to be blocking the main thread (all user interaction is non responsive) from the time I tap the button to when `prepareForSegue:sender:` gets called. However, if I do `RACSignal starWithScheduler:block` and pass in `[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]` for the scheduler, it executes as I would expect. So what am I missing here? Honestly, this stuff makes me feel like an idiot, maybe I should go back to "Haskell for pre-K" before I tackle this stuff.

Comment: @terrylewis Are you using the latest version of the code above (with `+start:` inside the signal block)? I also added a `-deliverOn:` to the flattened signal, to make sure that the segue is performed on the main thread. Sorry about all of the complexity! Commands are generally more complicated to use and understand than the rest of the framework.

Comment: Yeah, I had the latest version of the code. Here is a gist of what I currently have that is working, [link](https://gist.github.com/tLewisII/5667301)

Comment: @terrylewis What happens if you replace `RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler` with `[RACScheduler scheduler]`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30795/discussion-between-terry-lewis-and-justin-spahr-summers)

Comment: `[RACScheduler scheduler]` gives me the same problems as before. `+start:` is just a convenience method for `startWithScheduler:block:` that uses `[RACScheduler scheduler]` for the scheduler.

Comment: @terrylewis Can you please [file an issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues)? The behavior you're running into is quite unexpected. Running on the main thread should result in more blocking than running on a background scheduler, so it's not clear to me what could be happening.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with the framework, I've found that there's very little reason to use `RACSubject` directly, especially for one-off signals like this.  RACSubjects represent mutable signals, which you do not need in this case, and can actually increase the complexity of your code.  It would be far better for you to return a vanilla signal (through `+[RACSignal createSignal:]`) inside that command block, then have the resulting request code make up the body of the signal:

```
[[[command addSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id value) {
    //
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        //Request code here
            return nil;
    }];
}]switchToLatest]deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];
```

Or, better still, you can refactor `getArrayFromUri:error:` to return a signal and get rid of that ternary statement:

```
 [[[command addSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id value) {
     return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        //...
        [[self getArrayFromUri:@"/States"]subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
        } completed:^{
            [subscriber sendNext:array];
        }];
            return nil;
        }];
  }]switchToLatest]deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];
```

As for the problem of the subscription on the next line, those can be considered side effects of the signal, so we can make them explicitly so with the corresponding variants of `do:` applied to the signal for the command:

```
    [[[command addSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id value) {
        return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
            [[[[self getArrayFromUri:@"/States"]doError:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"the error = %@", error.localizedDescription);
                [subscriber sendError:err];
            }] doNext:^(NSArray *array) {
                [subscriber sendNext:array];
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSomeSegue sender:array];
            }] subscribeCompleted:^{
                [subscriber sendCompleted];
            }];
            return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
                 // Cleanup
            }];
        }];
    }]switchToLatest]deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];
```

Finally, because commands work a differently from signals, the outermost operators will not be evaluated (thanks, @jspahrsummers), so you can remove them.

```
[command addSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id value) {
            return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
                [[[[self getArrayFromUri:@"/States"]doError:^(NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"the error = %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    [subscriber sendError:err];
                }] doNext:^(NSArray *array) {
                    [subscriber sendNext:array];
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSomeSegue sender:array];
                }] subscribeCompleted:^{
                    [subscriber sendCompleted];
                }];
                return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
                     // Cleanup
                }];
            }];
        }];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot refactor `getArrayFromUri:error` as it is a third party framework and I only have access to the headers. I did however switch everything to the way you have it, and it does work just the same. Learning this feels like starting from the beginning all over again almost.

Comment: Yeah, the framework certainly does have a painfully steep learning curve, but once you get around to learning how it works, it's really powerful.

Comment: @CodaFi `switchToLatest]deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]` is a no-op in all of the samples you've provided, since no subscription occurs afterward. Same with your `-do…` methods.

Comment: Yes, I understand (probably should iterated that in the body of the post).

Comment: In the `do` case for your final code sample, I mean that _the network request will never fire_, because there's no subscription there.

Comment: Yes, so I'll change that to `subscribeCompleted:` and move the side effects into that